# Magento multiple stores creating gives error

Tags: magento-1.7

I am creating multiple stores in magento on wamp .

I have used following steps.

1. Create category for new store.
2. Create website for new store.
3. create store view for new store.
4. created new folder in magento for store and copy paste index.php and .htaccess file.
5. Edited in index.php changed

`$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';`

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); to  Mage::run('store1', 'website');
```

where store1 is our new store .

1. I have changed url under web in admin section `http:localhost/magento/store1` for new store
2. Changed in index.php app/mage.php to ../app/mage.php.

   but giving error `c:\wamp\www\magento\store1../app/Mage.php was not found`

I am using `http://localhost/magento/store1/` for new store.

Comment: Have you tried this on WAMP with PHP 5.3 instead of 5.4?

Comment: 5.3.13 version of php I am using.

Comment: @ZOERULE I am getting error like https://snag.gy/YLwvBm.jpg, backend screenshot: https://snag.gy/I1mLRz.jpg how can i solve this error..

Answer (score 4):

Your path to Mage.php is incorrect, you need to change the path in the index.php to /../app/Mage.php (you are missing the first /).

Comment: I have solved this problem by changing the skin,js url.Thanks for help